# NopCommerce code creates multiple null reference exceptions while using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, nopcommerce

I am facing an issue currently with using [ASP.NET Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Extensions) for the NopCommerce website which I need to connect to my cross-platform application.

The code breaks when I call the API. It produces an exception at:

```
var scope = EngineContext.Current.ContainerManager.Scope()
```

In the `task.cs` page.

I have tried debugging the code, but the exception is not generated regularly; sometimes it comes and sometimes not. I did, however, find some points where it breaks:

`var sis = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>()`.

I have tried loading it till it loads. i.e., putting it inside a `while` statement as:

```
    var sis = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>()`
    while(sis == null)
    {
        sis = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>()
    }
```

And similarly, a few more instances. This implies it loads, but after a delay, maybe.

There was an instruction in the nopcommerece forum to update the `autofac` package, which I did.
    **All the Autofac Nugets are tried individually in Nop.Web**.

With reference to this link [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/43371/enginecontextcurrentresolvecommonsettings-not-registered.aspx), I have tried fixing, but it didn't solve my problem.

`I came to the conclusion that it has some issue with the Autofac DI settings (not sure)`. Or is it that NopCommerce is built not to support APIs?

---

As Mr. Rigueira suggested, I have tried to register the route from the route configuration class inside my plugin itself.

The route configuration for the API is here:

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "TestApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    });
}
```

Still, it does not seem to make any difference.

---

I tried registering the route from the Plugin in the normal pattern:

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "WebApi",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "WebApi", action = "", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Nop.Plugin.WebApi.EduAwake.Controllers" }
                );
}
```

Still no go.
here's the error i get :

`Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Topic'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.`

`Line 13:                         <div class="col-md-12 padding-0" id="home-topic" style="margin-left:-14px;">
Line 14:                             <div id="home-topic-content" style="width:104%;">
Line 15:                                 @Html.Action("TopicBlock", "Topic", new { systemName = "HomePageText" })
Line 16:                             </div>
Line 17:                         </div>`
 in **index.cshtml**.

this seems to be a hopeless condition.

I have been working on this since months!

Comment: *is it that NopCommerce is built not to support APIs?* what do you mean?
of course it supports to API

Comment: What you want to achieve, the question is not cleared, what exception you get?

Comment: @Div the Exception thrown is null reference exception,
that's why try repeatedly until some value is assigns to the variable using while loop.

I have written many APIs used to hook with the functions of nopcommerce. but they work very inconsistently due to this exception!

Comment: @Div scope = ?scope
Tag = "AutofacWebRequest", IsDisposed = false
    ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning: null
    ComponentRegistry: {Autofac.Core.Registration.CopyOnWriteRegistry}
    CurrentScopeEnding: null
    Disposer: {Autofac.Core.Disposer}
    IsDisposed: false
    ParentLifetimeScope: Tag = "root", IsDisposed = false
    ResolveOperationBeginning: null
    RootLifetimeScope: Tag = "root", IsDisposed = false
    Tag: "AutofacWebRequest"
    _componentRegistry: {Autofac.Core.Registration.CopyOnWriteRegistry}

Comment: _disposer: {Autofac.Core.Disposer}
    _isDisposed: 0
    _parent: Tag = "root", IsDisposed = false
    _root: Tag = "root", IsDisposed = false
    _sharedInstances: Count = 4
    _synchRoot: {object}
    _tag: "AutofacWebRequest"

Comment: It is likely the error you're facing with task.cs is unrelated to webapi. Check if the thread that is having the error is the one actually serving the request or check if there is a httpcontext available. Check also the call stack and see where the call comes from. Also the second part seems unrelated to task.cs, pointing that you're requesting instances from the container too soon and they have not been registered yet (as strange it might seem), more info and detailed errors are needed for proper diagnostics.

Comment: @MarcoRegueira i have routed the calls to the webApiControler class that i created inside the Nop.Web

xx.com/api/controller is how i have given the route as.and i am registering this from another controller referenced in global.asax.cs

does the App_Start() function in anyways interrupt the task threads already scheduled

I mean, this is too confusing for a beginner like me...
i did not get any useful info from any of the forums!

Comment: I have the strong urge to blame dependency injection regardless of where the error lies. My experience tells me that dependency injection always makes understanding how the code flows *harder* and leads to less maintainability.

Comment: @jpmc26 but DI is supposed to ease maintainability right?

Comment: It's supposed to, but I find it creates scattered code that's difficult to follow and understand how the different pieces connect. It also seems to have a tendency to hide the real source of errors, instead converting an error constructing one object into a null reference or other kind of error. If it *can* be used to improve maintainability, then like almost anything in software, most be applied carefully and wisely. It cannot be blindly used for everything and result in an improvement; there are *no* silver bullets.

Comment: @MarcoRegueira i am changing the normal route which is {controller}/{action}/{id} with api/{controller}/{action}/{id} right?

Comment: @MarcoRegueira i was not able to access it form my phone the other way round..! May i have your e-mail address... please.

Answer (score 1):

Checking your code would be advisable but, most likely, you have by-passed nopcommerce when registering Web API, and now you're trying to use dependencies before they have been registered in the usual flow. That's why they eventually appear while you're waiting in the loop (I can't imagine how you have found such a workaround anyway...).

As a solution, you should integrate Web API using a plugin and not by modifying the original source code. I did it in the past, and it is not hard. There used to be a couple of samples for that if I don't recall badly.

Comment: could you please help me with any reference to some code examples.

i have found no examples of code, whatever i found  are dlls.
too much confusion!

**Debugging is very tedious because this exception does not occur everytime, not at all consistent.**

Comment: i changed the route registration to be inside the plugin itself, still producing the same exception at the same place......